# how does $\det((\det A) I)= (\det A)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Taking determinants of both sides of $A (\text{adj} A) = (\det A) I$, we have $$\det((A) (\text{adj} A))= \det((\det A) I) \text{ or } (\det A) (\det(\text{adj} A)) = (\det A)^n$$

When looking at the solution for this proof how does one reach from $\det((\det A) I)$ to $(\det A)^n$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  The determinant of a diagonal matrix is equal to the product of its diagonal entries.

Answer (score 2):

$det(A)I$ is a diagonal matrix with all entries equal to $det(A)$. The determinant of a diagonal matrix can be found by multiplying the diagonal entries. So, we get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = c I$, where $c$ is a scalar.

Then $\det A = \sum_\sigma \operatorname{ sgn} \sigma [A]_{1,\sigma_1} \cdots \sigma [A]_{n,\sigma_n}$. We have $[A]_{ij} = c \delta_{ij}$, and so
$\det A = c^n\sum_\sigma \operatorname{ sgn} \sigma \delta_{1,\sigma_1} \cdots \delta_{n,\sigma_n}$. Since $\delta_{1,\sigma_1} \cdots \delta_{n,\sigma_n} = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } \sigma_k = k \ \forall k \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, we have
$\det A = c^n$.